# Is it possible to extend a drive virtually into another?

Tags: windows, partitioning

Right now, I'm using my small SSD for my Windows 7 system. I have a larger 1TB secondary disk for storage. Is it possible to expand the SSD into a partition of the secondary disk so that the OS thinks its all one disk?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is something like what you are looking for?

When you format a disk you can choose to not assign a drive letter and instead assign a mount point to the drive. A mount point can thought of a directory that connects to the drive instead of a drive letter. So for example instead of `E:` for your storage disk you could assign it to `C:\Storage`. While this may look like a directory it is instead a kind of pointer that represents your 1TB disk.

Sorry if my example is a little strange.

Here is an article that can kind of explain what I am referring to. While it is referring to servers the point still stands on Window 7.

[Link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/use-mount-points-if-you-run-out-of-windows-drive-letters/)

Answer (score 1):

You can span one partition across multiple drives via the Disk Management snap-in in the Computer Management tool (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772180.aspx).  You will need to convert the disks from basic to dynamic disks first.  However, this functionality is not supported on the system partition (the C: drive).  In your situation, you'd probably be best to use one of the two methods already suggested.

Comment: Please note that doing this won't make Windows use the SSD as any form of cache, which may be what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Solignis said you have the option to create junctions.

```
mklink /J "c:\Program Files" "d:\Program Files"
mklink /J "c:\Program Files (x86)" "d:\Program Files (x86)"
```

YOU WILL HAVE TO RENAME/MOVE the original "c:\program files" (or etc) first